# Can't understand How to import a Database to my application in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a Ready Database (build with SqliteManager) that i went to import to my app in eclipse i found a lot of example that show how to build a Database but nothing how to copy to a database i would like to know if its exist any full example.

Thank to all of you!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I used the directions in [this tutorial](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) to copy my database from my assets folder to the database folder.